# Changing default field Input Value Raster for Zonal Statistics as Table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I have a raster in ArcGIS 10 with the following attribute table:
[image: atributetable]

When I try to use the tool Zonal Statistics as Table over some polygons, it calculates the statistics of the fields 'Value' and 'Count'.
My goal is to keep the column 'Count', and give the values of the field 'Projection'to the field 'Value'.
Then it will be possible to use Zonal Statistics with the real values (922, 859, 929...) and their 'Count'.

If I use the tool 'Delete field' on 'Value', all the numbers move a column to the left.

If I use 'Reclassify', then I could manage to do it giving values one by one, but as there are thousands of values, and many more layers, this path is unfeasible for me...

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new raster where the cell values will come from the "project" field of this raster using the spatial analyst tool called "Lookup."